# Is $AA^T$ a positive-definite symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ be a matrix. Is it true that $AA^{T}$ is positive-definite?

Clearly $AA^{T}$ is symmetric. I have shown that a symmetric matrix $S\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is positive-definite if and only if $S$ has only positive eigenvalues. Can this be helpful?

Comment: What if $A$ is zero?

Comment: it is always positive semi-definite

Comment: possible duplicate of [help me understand a line in an “$A^TA$ is positive, semi-definite” proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133350/help-me-understand-a-line-in-an-ata-is-positive-semi-definite-proof)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Hint: let $v$ be a non zero vector; then, setting $B=A^T$ for simplicity,
$$
v^TB^TBv=(Bv)^T(Bv)
$$
is positive if and only if $Bv\ne 0$. How can you ensure that $Bv\ne0$ if and only if $v\ne0$?

Conversely, if $AA^T$ is positive definite, what can you say about the rank of $A$?

So, what's a necessary and sufficient condition so that $AA^T$ is positive definite?

Comment: Is it also true for matrices over complex field? i.e Is $AA^*$ always positive definite?

Comment: @junk Positive *semi*definite; $A$ needs to be invertible for $AA^*$ to be positive definite (if $A^*$ denotes the Hermitian transpose, of course). The proof is essentially the same.

Comment: Does this also hold for non-square $A$?

Answer (score 17):

$AA^T$ is not necessarily positive definite, but it is positive semi-definite, meaning that $\langle x, AA^Tx \rangle \ge 0$ for all vectors $x$.  To see this, note that $\langle x, AA^Tx \rangle  = \langle A^Tx, A^Tx \rangle = \Vert A^Tx \Vert^2 \ge 0$.  A counter example to positive definiteness is provided, when $n = 2$, by taking

$A= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}; \tag{1}$

then

$AA^T = A, \tag{2}$

so if $x = (0, 1)^T$,

$\langle x, AA^Tx \rangle = 0. \tag{3}$

It  is easy to generalize this example by taking $A$ to be a diagonal matrix in $M_{n \times n}(\Bbb R)$ with at least one zero on the diagonal; many other generalizations are also possible.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: but if we take A to be non-singular, then it will positive definite, right?

Comment: Yes, if $A$ is nonsingular, so is $A^T$, since $(A^T)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^T$.  Thus for any $x$, $A^Tx \ne 0$, whence $\Vert A^Tx \Vert \ne 0$.  But it is easy to see that $\langle A^T x, A^T x \rangle = \langle x, AA^T x \rangle$.

Comment: Is it also true for matrices over complex field? i.e Is $AA^*$ always positive definite?

Comment: @Ziva:  if by $A^\ast$ you mean what is customarily denoted by $A^\dagger$, the Hermitian adjoint of $A$, the answer is affirmative.  If $A^\ast$ is merely the complex conjugate of $A$, I doubt it, but have no counter examples to offer at present.

Answer (score 0):

For a matrix to be positive definite we need $x^TMx \geq0$.
Consider the case where the matrix A is not full rank so therefore has more rows than columns.  It should be clear there exist a vector $x$ where $ x \neq 0 $, such that $x^TA = 0$.  Thus we have $x^TAA^Tx = 0$  Therefore $AA^T$ cannot be strictly positive definite.  (But you can show it is always semi-positive definite.)

Comment: This is imprecise, and somewhat wrong, even though the idea is OK. 1. "A is not full rank" should be "A is not full **row** rank". 2. "therefore has more rows than columns" is wrong, because "not full (row) rank" does not necessarily imply that it "has more rows than columns". Zero matrix is an obvious counter-example, but you can take any matrix with more than one row, and more columns than rows (so called *wide* matrix) and all of the rows mutually equal. It will not have a full (row) rank, but it will also have more columns than rows.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a positive definite but clearly it is positive semidefinite. Consider the general complex case, and consider $AA^*$ which is Hermitian.
$<AA^*x,x>=<A^*x,A^*x>=||A^*x|| \geq 0 \forall x$. Therefore, $AA^*$ is positive semidefinite.
Clearly, if $A$ is real, then A is symmetric i.e. $A^*=A^T$ since $\overline {a_{ij}}=a_{ij}$.

However, if you want it to be positive look at $V\backslash\{0\}$ and $A$ injective.