# Given A $m\times n$, $\{u_1,...,u_n\}$ ON basis of $R^n$, prove eigenvalues aren't negative

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality, orthonormal, svd

**Given** **$A$** $(m\times n)$, $\{u_1,...,u_n\}$ ON(orthonormal) basis of $R^n$ which are eigenvectors of $A^TA$ with $\lambda_1 , ... , \lambda_n$ eigenvalues accordingly.

Prove: Eigenvalues are not negative, $Au_1,..,Au_n$ are orthogonal basis of $R^n$.

Any ideas, hints how to prove it are appreciated.

Edit: I believe I'll find the proof of the first part soon in the book, so I'll update as soon as possible.

Comment: if $A\in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$, then $Au\in \mathbb R^m$, so they can't be elements of $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: There's also [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730421/is-aat-a-positive-definite-symmetric-matrix).