# How can I show these properties of $B^TB$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $B$ be some matrix in $\Bbb{R}^{k*n}$ and define $A=B^TB\hspace{0.5cm}(A\in\Bbb{R}^{n*n}$)

How can I show that $A$ is symmetric and positive-semidefinite and that A is strictly positive-definite if and only if $ker(B)=\{0\}$?

I've tried this: $x^TAx=x^TB^TBx=(Bx)^T(Bx)\geq0$, hence it is positive-semidefinite. Then, how can I show that it is symmetric?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is $AA^T$ a positive-definite symmetric matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730421/is-aat-a-positive-definite-symmetric-matrix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep going.

- Showing that $A$ is symmetric is trivial:
  $$
  A^t=(B^tB)^t=B^t(B^t)^t=B^tB=...
  $$
- Notice that $y^ty=\|y\|^2\ge 0$ for any vector $y$; particularly for $y=Bx$. This, with your attempt together, gives you the positive semidefiniteness of $A$.
- Suppose $A$ is strictly positive definite. Then your attempt shows that $Bx=0$ implies $x=0$. On the other hand, if $Bx=0$, then your attempt also shows that
  $x^tAx=0$ and thus $x=0$.